# ASP.NET Core WebAPI external login profile data

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api

The front end is already authenticated with Google/Facebook/Twitter.

I just need to use the id token from the front end to get the user profile info in the WebApi, check if we already have an account with that email etc. and if not then add the external login key to the Identity data (by calling AddLoginAsync on the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager).

I don't want to hardcode the user profile endpoints for Google, Facebook etc. as they might change. I'd like to use something like a NuGet package that has these values and just update it when/if they change.

I've read a lot of examples but they're for whole authentication flows, using redirects and cookies in Asp.Net MVC... Although it seems basic, I didn't find an example where the external login is already done on the client and the backend just needs to use the resulting token to validate that login and get the user profile info.

Anyone else ran into this? Thanks!